# Knockout JS pattern for multiple viewmodels in same page maintaining DOM structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I recently got started with knockout js. I'm trying to use it in a project in what seems to be a non-traditional manner. I need to maintain the DOM IDs and structure as emitted by server-side code. However, I would like to utilize knockout to facilitate client-side operations, by utilizing a pattern to reference fields on the page as javascript objects.

I have a proof-of-concept snippet working, but I'm wondering how well it will scale when I start adding more sections. I would like to get some feedback to see what more experienced knockout users have to say.

Example in these [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcbbg81/woqtzLk2/), [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcbbg81/woqtzLk2/32/):
e.g.:

HTML

```html
<!-- 
  * We would then have a whole other section like fieldset0 after fieldset0 for a different people category
  * We need to use the ids returned by the page, just add knockout on top without modifying DOM structure (except for sorting people based on sort order field, after removing item2 and adding again, it should go after item3 - if all 3 were on the page)
-->

<fieldset name="fieldset0" id="el_fieldset0">
    <fieldset name="fieldset1" id="el_fieldset1">
         <h1><span id="person1"></span></h1>

        <input id="hasdata1" type="hidden" value="Yes" />
        <label for="name1">name</label>
        <input id="name1" value="andrew" />
        <label for="age1">age</label>
        <input id="age1" value="30" />
        <label for="grade1">grade</label>
        <select id="grade1">
            <option selected>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>F</option>
        </select> <a id="remove1" class="remove" href="javascript:void(0)">remove</a>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="fieldset2" id="el_fieldset2">
         <h1><span id="person2"></span></h1>

        <input id="hasdata2" type="hidden" value="Yes" />
        <label for="name2">name</label>
        <input id="name2" value="brandon" />
        <label for="age2">age</label>
        <input id="age2" value="40" />
        <label for="grade2">grade</label>
        <select id="grade2">
            <option>A</option>
            <option selected>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
        </select> <a id="remove2" class="remove" href="javascript:void(0)">remove</a>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="fieldset3" id="el_fieldset3">
         <h1><span id="person3"></span></h1>

        <input id="hasdata3" type="hidden" value="" />
        <label for="name3">name</label>
        <input id="name3" value="calvin" />
        <label for="age3">age</label>
        <input id="age3" value="50" />
        <label for="grade3">grade</label>
        <select id="grade3">
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option selected>C</option>
        </select> <a id="remove3" class="remove" href="javascript:void(0)">remove</a>

    </fieldset> <a id="addItem" class="add" href="javascript:void(0)">add</a>

</fieldset>
```

Javascript

```js
var myNamespace = {};

$(document).ready(function () {

    //assign fieldset variables
    myNamespace.$fieldset0 = $("#el_fieldset0"); // parent for all items
    //individual items
    myNamespace.$fieldset1 = $("#el_fieldset1");
    myNamespace.$fieldset2 = $("#el_fieldset2");
    myNamespace.$fieldset3 = $("#el_fieldset3");
    //set the number of objects
    myNamespace.personObjectCount = 3;

    //set utilityArrays
    myNamespace.personObjects = [];
    myNamespace.availablePersonObject = [];

    //assign data-bind attributes to html
    for (var i = 0; i < myNamespace.personObjectCount; i++) {
        var objectIndex = i + 1;
        var currentFielsetStr = "$fieldset" + objectIndex;

        //myNamespace[currentFielsetStr] = $("#el_fieldset"+ objectIndex);
        myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("input[id^='name']").attr("data-bind", "value: personName");
        myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("input[id^='age']").attr("data-bind", "value: personAge");
        myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("select[id^='grade']").attr("data-bind", "value: personGrade");
        myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("span[id^='person']").attr("data-bind", "text: personTitle");
        myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("input[id^='hasdata']").attr("data-bind", "value: hasData");

        //hasdata identifies visibility and should wipe fields when set to false
        myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].attr("data-bind", "visible: hasData() === 'Yes'");

        //remove link associates with removeItem function
        myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("a[id^='remove']").attr("data-bind", "click: removeItem");

        //create each viewmodel object
        myNamespace.personObjects.push({
            "name": myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("input[id^='name']").val(),
                "age": myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("input[id^='age']").val(),
                "grade": myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("select[id^='grade']").val(),
                "hasData": myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].find("input[id^='hasdata']").val(),
                "parentFieldset": myNamespace[currentFielsetStr]
        });

        /*
        //attach event handlers
        myNamespace[currentFielsetStr].on("click", ".remove", function () {
            //retrieve the ko context
            var context = ko.contextFor(this);
            debugger;
            //alert(context);
        });
*/

        //populate available person array
        if (myNamespace.personObjects[i].hasData !== "Yes") {
            debugger;
            myNamespace.availablePersonObject.push(myNamespace.personObjects[i]);
        }
    }

    //add link associates with addItem function, disables if at maximum count/no positions available -- only one per section -- should try to move to binding outside of these (make a root viewmodel for the page containing individual sections?)
    //debugger;
    myNamespace.$fieldset0.find("a[id^='addItem']")
        .attr("data-bind", "click: addItem, enabled: myNamespace.availablePersonObject.length > 0")
        .click(function () {
        debugger;
        if (myNamespace.availablePersonObject.length > 0) {
            //add first item in lsit of available person object (later, based on sort order)
            myNamespace.availablePersonObject[0].parentFieldset.find("input[id^='hasdata']").val("Yes").change();
            myNamespace.availablePersonObject.splice(0, 1);
        }
        if (myNamespace.availablePersonObject.length < 1) {
            //disable add button
        }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < myNamespace.personObjects.length; i++) {
        //perform knockout bindings
        ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel(myNamespace.personObjects[i]), myNamespace.personObjects[i].parentFieldset[0]);
    }
});

function myViewModel(personObject) {
    var self = this;

    self.personName = ko.observable(personObject.name);
    self.personAge = ko.observable(personObject.age);
    self.personGrade = ko.observable(personObject.grade);
    self.hasData = ko.observable(personObject.hasData);

    self.personTitle = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.personName() + " : " + self.personGrade();
    });

    self.removeItem = function () {
        debugger;
        var _blank = "";
        //var _blank = undefined;
        self.hasData(_blank);
        self.personName(_blank);
        self.personAge(_blank);
        self.personGrade(_blank);

        myNamespace.availablePersonObject.push(personObject);
    };

    /*
    self.addItem = function() {
        //move this to outside the individual element and add to the parent Section
        //or maybe don't have the fields at all
        debugger;        
    };
    */
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to maintain the DOM Id's and Structure? If its to do with saving (POST, PUT, etc) the data back to the server then I would consider creating a save function that replicates the data format needed by the server. At the moment it looks like you are inviting a world of hurt by being inflexible and not playing to knockouts strengths.

Comment: Indeed, @NathanFisher! Meet my pain :)

But those are the constraints I must work within for this one, at least.

I have a better/smaller scale proof of concept created(http://jsfiddle.net/vcbbg81/vv3zjag4/18/), but there are a few things I still need to fulfill some requirements, such as sorting based on a sortOrder value. Do you know a way to get the DOM element the viewModel is currently using? Or do I just need to track that as part of an external objectArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented a solution for the type of issue I needed to address.

I've essentially broke the task in 4 parts for binding to inflexible generated HTML. This would maintain specific DOM ids while binding (no dynamic html generation for these purposes) (this is done for each object-viewModel binding abstraction):

1. Create a model dataObject to be bound to the ViewModel (this is read from the existing HTML Markup after page is loaded, client-side. Also store information for each of our "objects" in this dataObject, including the ViewModel to be returned by knockout and the fieldset knockout should use for binding.
2. Apply bindings using jQuery and dataObject information -- could be combined w/ step 1.
3. Create ViewModel based on initial dataObject values.
4. Apply knockout bindings to page using dataObject's viewModel

Rough sample listed in this http://jsfiddle.net/vcbbg81/vv3zjag4/79/

```
$("#pageMenu1").before("<!-- ko stopBinding: true -->");
    $("#pageMenu1").after("<!-- /ko -->");

    //$("#employmentMenu1").attr("data-bind", "checked: employmentMenuItem");
    myNamespace.vmPage = {
        "employmentMenuItem": $("#employmentMenu1").attr("data-bind", "checked: employmentMenuItem").prop("checked"),
            "selfEmploymentMenuItem": $("#selfEmploymentMenu1").attr("data-bind", "checked: selfEmploymentMenuItem").prop("checked"),
            "otherMenuItem": $("#otherMenu1").attr("data-bind", "checked: otherMenuItem").prop("checked"),
            "noneMenuItem": $("#noneMenu1").attr("data-bind", "checked: noneMenuItem").prop("checked")
    };

    //myNamespace.vmPage = pageObjects;
    myNamespace.vmPage.viewModel = new aPageViewModel(myNamespace.vmPage);
    ko.applyBindings(myNamespace.vmPage.viewModel, $("#pageMenu1")[0]);
```